# C++ unable to delete a node in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to delete a node in a linked list using **mylist.erase();** but the node remains in the list. I tried to use **delete()** but the program crashes. Any idea?

```
list <Person*> :: iterator it;
it = gamelist.begin(); //gamelist is a <Person*> list. it is an iterator to this list.
while (it!=gamelist.end()){
    if ((*it)->is_dead == true) {
        delete (*it); //if I comment this line the program does not crash but the "dead" Person still remains in the list.
        it = gamelist.erase(it);
    }
    else ++it;
}
```

Comment: Hi did you try   to gamelist.erase and then delete?

Comment: Hi @JuanPablo. Yes, I tried it. Same problem...

Comment: Are you sure that you `new`ed the memory @ `*it` and that it is not already freed? You can try saving `*it` in a temporary `Person *`, do the erase and delete the temporary.

Comment: Why do you use `Person *` instead of some smart pointer?

Comment: Welcome to C++. Just because some chunk of code crashes at one particular point, it doesn't mean that's exactly where the bug is. It is not possible to answer your question without a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

Deleting a pointer has no effect on whether the pointer remains in a container. Since you haven't shown a program that demonstrates that shows that the node remains in the list, I posit that it does not remain after the call to `erase`.

If you allocated the pointed object with `new`, then you must `delete` it at some point. If the program crashes when you delete the pointer here, that means that either

- The pointer is uninitialized and has never pointed to a valid object.
- The pointer used to be valid, but the pointed object has already been destroyed, and the pointer is no longer valid.
- The pointer is valid, but points to an object that was not created with `new`.
- The pointed object is not in a valid state that its destructor depends on.

It is not possible to "test" the validity of the pointer within the program (except for checking whether it is null, but deleting null is OK and would not crash, so that's not the problem in your case). You must analyze your program and guarantee the validity yourself. Smart pointers make reasoning about the validity of pointers far easier. I recommend you to use them.

Comment: So for Theo, the bottomline is that you should check your code where you _insert_ elements into your list, and make sure that they are either pointers created with `new`, or `NULL`.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn there is never need to check that a pointer is not null when deleting it. The pointer is required point to a valid object only if it is non-null.

Comment: "In all cases, if ptr is a null pointer, the standard library deallocation functions do nothing." [[C++ std](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)] I did not know that, thanks. I edited my previous comment. :)